# Tips and tricks for working with Microsoft Visual Studio solutions and project

Tags: visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

After answering on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45650/common-files-in-visual-studio-solution#45664) I thought it would be nice to collect some tips & tricks for working with MSVS solutions and projects.

Here is my list:

- How to avoid saving new projects
  automatically to reduce garbage in
  file system.

  Uncheck **Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Save new projects when created**
- How to add common file to multiple
  projects without copying it to
  project’s directory.

  Right click on a project, select **Add->Existing Item->Add as link** (press on small arrow on Add button)
- How to add project to solution
  without including it in the build
  process

  Right click on solution, select **Add->New solution folder**.
  Right click on created folder, **select Add->Add existing project**
- How to edit project file from Visual
  Studio?

  Right click on project and select **Unload Project**, right click on unloaded project and select **Edit**.
  Or install [Power Commands](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerCommands) and select **Edit Project File**
- How to group files in the project
  tree (like auto-generated files for
  WinForms controls)

  Open project file for editing.

```
   Change
```

```
<Compile Include="MainFile.cs" />
<Compile Include="SecondaryFile.cs" />

To

<Compile Include="SecondaryFile.cs ">
    <DependentUpon> MainFile.cs </DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

Do you have anything else to add?

Comment: The "Add as link" thing, it doesn't work for web projects being developed locally as the file is not copied until web project is published. The file cannot be found physically on disk by the WebDev server, any solution?

Comment: And again, the most constructive questions getting closed as "not constructive"...

Answer (score 17):

First rule of working with Visual Studio:

- **Install [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)**

Answer (score 5):

I'm a huge fan of using msbuild to build my solutions with the /m option so that it builds using multiple cores. It can drastically decrease your build time.

Scott Hanselman posted on how to add it to your tools list at http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HackParallelMSBuildsFromWithinTheVisualStudioIDE.aspx.

I usually just run 'msbuild /m' from the command prompt or PowerShell, though.

Another tip that is sometimes useful is taking advantage of the pre- and post-build events to add additional logic before or after a build. To see these, go to the Properties for a Project, click on the Compile tab, and then choose "Build Events..."

Answer (score 4):

I love debugging with the [Multiple startup projects option](http://blogs.msdn.com/saraford/archive/2008/07/28/did-you-know-you-can-start-debugging-multiple-projects-268.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I like changing the default location that new projects are saved to.

Tools->Options (Select Projects and Solutions tab)

This "tab" has all sorts of goodness.  Not just the ability to change the default locations and avoid saving new projects automatically but other nice things as well.  For example:

Track Active Item - Selects the file in the solution explorer when you change windows.

Show Output window when build starts - Toggle to show or not.  I like it on, your mileage will vary.

Comment: Track Active Item in Solution Explorer is one of the features I regret are not on by default. So many people have gasped in wonder as I check the box and show them what it does.

Answer (score 2):

Using the command window to quickly open files in your solution:

1. Bring up the Command Window (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>)
2. Type `open <filename>`

I create an alias for `open` by executing the following at the Command Window: `alias o open`.  Visual Studio will remember the alias from then on, so I only ever need to type `o <filename>`.

It even searches database projects unlike some third-party plugins!

Unfortunately, there is a bug in the filename completion when searching for nested files.  A simple workaround is to type the beginning of the filename, hit the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key and then type the rest of the name.  To search for login.aspx.cs, type `login.aspx`, hit <kbd>ESCP</kbd> and then type `.cs`.

Comment: And how you create the alias for subsequent open in VS?

Comment: I didn't fully understand your question, but I hope my edit answers your question.  VS remembers the alias until you explicitly remove it.

Comment: You can also use the search box in the toolbar to open files by typing ">of filename" (it autocompletes but has the same problem mentioned above).

Comment: Yup, I used that for a while too.  Now, however, I just use ReSharper ;)

Answer (score 1):

I have a tip regarding the "Track Active Item" option mentioned above, for when working with big projects. It's posted here:

[Forcing the Solution Explorer to select the file in the editor in visual studio 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31163/forcing-the-solution-explorer-to-select-the-file-in-the-editor-in-visual-studio#46193)